# Can't call to php webservice with parameter

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-phone-8

This is my code and i wan't to call to webservice in windows phone application.

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/get_places_nearby.php?longitude="+itravelObj.getGPSLongitude()+"&latitude="+itravelObj.getGPSLatitude(), UriKind.Relative));
```

help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to change that URI to `UriKind.Relative` to `UriKind.Absolute`

```C#
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/get_places_nearby.php?
    longitude="+itravelObj.getGPSLongitude()+"&latitude="+itravelObj.getGPSLatitude(),
    UriKind.Relative));
```

Because you start with `http://www.website.com`